# Xamarin Data Binding - issue showing data from custom class via ItemList

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

I have the following class defined in the model:

```
public class Equipment
{

    public Equipment(string resName, DateTime crTime, int quant)
    {
        ResourceName = resName;
        CreateTime = crTime;
        Quantity = quant;
    }

    public string ResourceName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set;  }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }


}
```

I use a viewModel where I define it as

```
class EquipementViewModel : ObservableObject
   {
       ObservableCollection<Equipment> equipRange = new ObservableCollection<Equipment>();
       public ObservableCollection<Equipment> EquipRange { get { return equipRange; }  }
       public EquipementViewModel()
         {
                     
           equipRange.Add(new Equipment("Komax01",DateTime.Now,1));
           equipRange.Add(new Equipment("Komax02", DateTime.Now, 1));
           equipRange.Add(new Equipment("Komax03", DateTime.Now, 1));
       }
}
```

And then finally the View XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TestXamarin.ViewModels"
             x:Class="TestXamarin.Views.EquipementPage"
              Title="EQuip"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:EquipementViewModel">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:EquipementViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EquipRange}" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
         
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <TextCell TextColor="black" Text="{Binding ResourceName}">
                    <TextCell.BindingContext>
                        <viewmodels:EquipementViewModel/>
                    </TextCell.BindingContext></TextCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        
    </ListView>
  
</ContentPage>
```

I want for the TextCell to show the ResourceNasme of the Equipment class, but the VIsual Studio shows me an error that Member not found in the Data Context "Equipment View Model".

I watched numerous guides, and I don't think I'm doing something wrong. What could be the issue?

Comment: you don't need to specify a BindingContext for the TextCell

Comment: @Jason but how will the textcell show only the ResourceName instead of all 3 fields?

Comment: I said to remove the **BindingContext**, not `{Binding ResourceName}`.  The template will inherit the correct context automatically, you don't need to specify it

Comment: @Jason sadly does not work as well. I tried it now, but I also tried before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to supply a `BindingContext` for the `TextCell`.  It will inherit the correct `BindingContext` from the `ListView` automatically

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell TextColor="black" Text="{Binding ResourceName}">
                <TextCell.BindingContext>
                    <viewmodels:EquipementViewModel/>
                </TextCell.BindingContext></TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

instead just do this

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell TextColor="black" Text="{Binding ResourceName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was something I added later. I tried it without it before, it still shows the error sadly.

Comment: try getting rid of `x:DataType` too

Comment: Now that works! :-) Wow, I had no idea. I think I added this on some tutorial I watched.